# Blazor - Getting a bunch of errors when publishing the site

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, blazor

i have a blazor web app project that runs perfectly fine when i run the project but when i publish it to azure i get a bunch of errors which i didn't have before.
I know this isn't much to go on but these are the errors if anyone knows why they are happening.

```
[2024-02-28T15:18:57.082Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_blazor'.
dotnet.runtime.8.0.2.08ksuqn0ht.js:3 MONO_WASM: The version of dotnet.runtime.js is different from the version of dotnet.js!
pt @ dotnet.runtime.8.0.2.08ksuqn0ht.js:3
dotnet.runtime.8.0.2.08ksuqn0ht.js:3 MONO_WASM: The version of dotnet.native.js is different from the version of dotnet.js!
pt @ dotnet.runtime.8.0.2.08ksuqn0ht.js:3
blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'dqpunZywlYy86b4O6ZjONasmG+4FH0P17FZ0OIf/lIg='. The resource has been blocked.
blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
dotnet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.S [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4466)
    at dotnet.js:3:11710
    at dotnet.js:3:11726
blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'dqpunZywlYy86b4O6ZjONasmG+4FH0P17FZ0OIf/lIg='. The resource has been blocked.
blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
dotnet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.S [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4466)
    at dotnet.js:3:11710
    at dotnet.js:3:11726
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-02-28T15:18:58.257Z] Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.
log @ blazor.web.js:1
blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'dqpunZywlYy86b4O6ZjONasmG+4FH0P17FZ0OIf/lIg='. The resource has been blocked.
blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
blazor.web.js:1 Error in mono_download_assets: Error: download 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' for dotnet.native.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
Rr @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.S [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4466)
    at dotnet.js:3:11710
    at dotnet.js:3:11726
4dotnet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' for dotnet.native.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:10097
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8985)
    at async G (dotnet.js:3:8833)
dotnet.runtime.8.0.2.08ksuqn0ht.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' for dotnet.native.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:10097
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8985)
    at async G (dotnet.js:3:8833)
2blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' for dotnet.native.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:10097
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8985)
    at async G (dotnet.js:3:8833)
blazor.web.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://blazorenigmaweb.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.native.wasm' for dotnet.native.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:10097
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8985)
    at async G (dotnet.js:3:8833)
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: How are you publishing your blazor app? is it VS2022?

Comment: yes its vs2022, https://github.com/Kroplewski-M/BlazorEnigma this is the  code

Comment: Is that application runs successfully in local?

Comment: Your issue only while deploying the application into azure right?

Comment: yes runs perfectly locally and i just get the errors when i deploy to azure

Comment: Ok, I will check my end

Comment: Which dotnet version you are using?

Comment: Im using .net 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix these errors by deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders from the server and client app. Then re building the project. When I re-deployed the errors disappeared